# How to validate inputs from GET method? laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-validation

How can I validate my inputs from a GET method?

Example URL: `localhost:8000?salary=2000&name=sample&description=vowewljfodigjfdglfd`

In the URL I have 3 inputs and I want to validate:

- **Salary** - should accept only *numeric*
- **Name** - should accept only *alphabetic*
- **Description** - should accept with *max:1000*

Somebody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Laravel validator doesn't care where the data *came* from. You can [manually create a validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators) and pass it the query string data.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->query(), [
    'salary' => 'numeric',
    'name' => 'alpha_num',
    'description' => 'max:1000',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // show an error
}
```

Side note: As someone with a hyphenated last name, I *implore* you not to treat name as alphanumeric. See [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).